# on what bases tester will write test cases?

Tags: testing

Basing on what documents the test engineer will prepare test cases, directly from the requirement document or any other document. I heard that senior test engineer will prepare test scenarios based on requirement document, from test scenarios test engineer will prepare the test cases, is this the correct procedure or not please clarify me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Normally The flow is -
Use Case -> Functional Requirement Specification -> Test Scenario -> Test Conditions.

Now it depends on your company how particular they are in following this process.